# database query via javascript & servlet

Tags: javascript, database, servlets

I am trying to do a simple query for info from a database through an html page.  I've got all the backend stuff working fine, but I'm having trouble on the client side.  I currently have a form where the user submits their ID# to get some info on their case.

But with my current setup, it returns an entirely new page and I just want to read in a text string, process it and update the content on the current html page without opening up a new one and replacing the old one.  How can this be done?

Here's my code so far:

```
function showInfo() { } // I want to make the request here instead

<form name="register" action="http://localhost:8080/testapp/authenticate" method="get">
      <p><label for="badge">ID #:</label>
         <input id="badge" name="ID" type="text" pattern="[0-9]{6}"
                placeholder="xxxxxx">
         <button id="checkButton" type="submit" onClick="showInfo()">Enter</button>   
      </p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're actually submitting the form, which is posting back to the server. What you will want to do is cancel the form from submitting and submit it using AJAX (which is what I believe you want?).

To do so, your `showInfo()` function should do one of these three things (I can never remember which one)

1. `return false;`
2. cancel the event, something like `e.preventDefault()`
3. stop the propagation, something like `e.stopPropagation()`

Once you've successfully prevented the form from hard-submitting, you can then do what you'd like by submitting your data via AJAX and manipulating your response however you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

1st - Jason is absolutely right that what you want for this situation is AJAX, below is an example in motion.

2nd - You should be using a Javascript library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which might look intimidating (as it did for me at first), but it is really easy and completely worth the small effort to get it going.

3rd - With jQuery, your application tidbits should look something like this, using the example you provided:

HTML -

```
    <p>
        <label for="badge">ID #:</label>
        <input id="badge" name="ID" type="text" pattern="[0-9]{6}"
            placeholder="xxxxxx">
        // Please note that I removed the onClick section from the line below.
        <button id="checkButton" type="button">Enter</button>   
    </p>
```

JQUERY -

```
// The default function you described to take information and display it.
function showInfo(data) {
    // Insert your function here, probably using JSON as the Content Type
}

// This is the key AJAX function, using jQuery, that takes your info and gets a    
// response from the server side, the sends it to the function above in order for it 
// to be displayed on the page.
function processIdInfoCheck() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/http://localhost:8080/testapp/authenticate',
        data: { 
           'id': $('#badge').val();
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: displayIdInfoReturn,
        error: function () {
            alert("There was an error processing your request, please try again");
        }
    });
}

// When the page loads, the code below will trigger, and bind your button click        
// with the action you want, namely triggering the AJAX function above
(function ($) { 

    $('#checkButton').bind('click', processIdInfoCheck);

})(jQuery);
```

Just remember, AJAX takes some effort to get the desired effect, but when you look at page load times, request numbers, etc... It is totally worth it.  Please let me know if this was helpful and if you need any specifics.

Comment: Wow, this reply is really helpful.  Yes, I'm somewhat familiar with JQuery and really like what little I know about it.  Unfortunately this code didn't work.  It says "can't find localhost:8080" even though I can pull it up in the browser

Comment: Don't forget that you are going to need to configure your web.xml file to give access to the servlet. That is going to take something called servlet mapping, which you can find examples of through google.  Servlet mapping will also help you shorten the url used in the AJAX request, as you can call the url whatever you want. In your case, the url would probably just be "/authenticate". Also, if you like the answer, please mark it as answered or at least up vote it, thank you!

Comment: Owen, thanks for all the advice. I actually have it all working now. I found this little snippit out in the web and it finds the servlet correctly:  $.get("authenticate", {badge:$('input#badge').val()}, function(xml) { 
            displayFamilyInfoReturn(xml);
        });  
  Again, thanks for all the help!

Comment: Your welcome! Can you also please up-vote or accept my answer, this allows me to do more stuff on the site rather than just the plain old vanilla q&a, thanks.